# AWS Cloudformation output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a `CloudFormation` template for users which will create instances and give an application end point and user name and password. I am able to achieve unique application endpoint with respect to instance ID but I am not able to generate a dynamic username. Could any one help with the function that should be used to achieve different username on every new attempt. Below is the sample.

```
"Outputs" : {
"EndpointURL" : { 
  "Description" : "Application End Point",
  "Value" :  { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "http://", { "Ref" : "DNS****"}]]}
  },
  "Username" : {
   "Description" : "Dynamic Username required",
   "Value" :  "**********.com"
  },    
  "Password" : {
   "Description" : "Password",
   "Value" :  "Fixed"
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Custom Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html) to create anything that CloudFormation does not support natively. In your case, generating random usernames, that probably can be implemented using [Lambda Custom Resources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-cloudformation-update-lambda-backed-custom-resources-more/).

It is also possible to launch an instance that computes whatever required, but i'd consider lambda custom resources as it is the simplest way to customize CloudFormation.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using your approach.

Please review your application architecture. If you're looking into getting `DNS records` for your instances, you need to register those instances with `Route 53` records from withing the instances themselves.

If you really need to generate usernames and access credentials, I'd use `IAM` resources from within `CloudFormation`.